# How to make a KESSEBOHMER hinge mechanism lift more weight?

Tags: kitchens, hinges, cupboard

I have a wall-mounted cupboard that I bought some about 7 years ago. It has a lift-up front face which is driven by a [KESSEBOHMER](https://www.kesseboehmer.com/en/storage-solutions/kitchen/wall-units/overview) hinge mechanism. The face falls when lifted, apparently a common issue that can be fixed by strengthening the spring inside. Unfortunately I could not find my exact one in [their catalog](https://www.kesseboehmer.digital/epaper/index.html?catalog=catalogue-english&lang=en).

It looks like this:

[image]

There are `+` and `-` indications. The ones on the right, next to the screw, are there to fine-adjust the height of the mechanism - when turning the screw the whole system moves up or down a bit. I do not know what the other `+/-` (the one on the left) means.

I wanted to ask if **someone has ever adjusted this mechanism before?** The thing that worries me is that I do not see any visible way to adjust the force of the spring.

EDIT: the two holes on the left of the two screws (the lower one is also on the right of the quasi-vertical `← + - →` sign) are just mounting holes for the cover that comes on top of the mechanism. They are empty.

EDIT: the piston is a breaking mechanism to slow down the **falling** facing, it does not take part in maintaining it lifted (I checked that on the other, correctly working hinges)

Comment: Is there a screw or hex head in the hole to the right of the left (linear) +/- marking? Have you rotated that screw left/right?

Comment: why are you asking here? ... contact the manufacturer

Comment: @jsotola: I did it already, but no response. This is the fallback solution, hoping someone has one.

Comment: @JonCuster: they are mounting holes - I updated my question with that information

Comment: I do think the manufacturer (/one of their distributors) will solve this, but can you pull out the piston? Does it twist one way or another to increase preload?

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate: yes, I can pull it but it is not part of the living mechanism (I updated my question with this detail)

Comment: I see… if this is the often-used cabinet and one of the others is less popular, a temporary fix might be to switch mechanisms. Worst case, there are new door lift mechanisms readily available, but that would involve different screw holes, which is bothersome.

Comment: please add pictures in closed position and 1/2 open position ... use camera timer, or a voice command, to take picture with door closed ... and one same as above, but from further away, so all of the mechanism is visible

Answer (score 1):

1. "I do not know what the other +/- (the one on the left) means." If there is no adjustment mechanism there, perhaps part of the hinge is missing, e.g., an additional spring and tensioning screw to adjust the lift of the hinge? Or is that hole by the arrow point, in what appears to be a sliding bar, used to slide it along that track to adjust tension?
2. On a [balanced-arm lamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced-arm_lamp) that drooped when a heavy LED replaced the incandescent lamp, I added an elastic band cut from automotive inner tube around the existing posts holding the spring, and achieved good balance. You might try something similar around the red and gray part that looks like a combined pneumatic delay and spring. To achieve different length rubber bands from the inner tube, cut *diagonally*, rather than straight across.

Comment: *perhaps part of the hinge is missing* - unfortunately no, I have three other identical hinges that look the same (and work fine) and they are identical.

Comment: *Or is that hole by the arrow point* → they are mounting holes - I updated my question with that information